# var_dump returns null, can't figure out why

Tags: php, json

```
   <?php
     $json_string = file_get_contents('infile.json');
     fwrite($fileout, $json_string);
     var_dump(json_decode($json_string));
     $get_json_values=json_decode($json_string,true);
        if(is_array($get_json_values))
        {
        foreach ($get_json_values as $getlikes) {  ?>
          <li>
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/<?php echo $getlikes['id']; ?>" target="_top">
          </li>
        <?php
      } }
       ?>
```

I am trying to get values from a `json` file and I just can't figure out why `var_dump` returns NULL. Also, if I remove the `if`, for obvious reasons, there is a
`Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

Please help me with this, i've been working on this the whole day and it's just so frustrating that it doesn't work out in any way.

Note: The name of the file is correct, the file is in the same directory with the `.php` file, there is data in `infile.json` and **it is printed when** `fwrite($fileout, $json_string);` **is done**.

What would be the problem, and what should I do?

---

Edit: The `json` file has about 1000 entries containing facebook page data. They all have the following structure:

```
{"category":"Musician\/band","name":"Yann Tiersen (official)","id":"18359161762","created_time":"2013-03-09T23:00:54+0000"}
```

`var_dump($json_string)` prints the data from the file.

if this helps in any way, the `json` file can be downloaded [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gtqrzml1p9p5zpy/infile.json)

---

I have made up my json like this:

```
function idx(array $array, $key, $default = null) {
  return array_key_exists($key, $array) ? $array[$key] : $default;
}
$likes = idx($facebook->api('/me/likes'), 'data', array());
foreach ($likes as $like) {

                    fwrite($fileout,json_encode($like));
                    fwrite($fileout,PHP_EOL );
                  ?>`
```

So, what should I change would be:
1) add `fwrite($fileout, "[");` before and `fwrite($fileout,"]");` after `foreach`.
2) add `fwrite($fileout,",")` before `fwrite($fileout,PHP_EOL );`
Is this right?

Comment: Please show the contents of `infile.json`

Comment: `var_dump($json_string);` and paste the results. "NULL is returned if the json cannot be decoded or if the encoded data is deeper than the recursion limit. "

Comment: are you sure error checking and display are on?

Comment: @mkaatman there is no reason the encoded data would be deeper than the recursion limit, because the data was encoded using `json_encode`

Comment: @Dagon yes, it is, everything works fine.

Comment: @BujancaMihai: every _line_ in that file contains valid json, however, as a whole it's invalid (needs `[...,...,...]`. So, read line for line (use `fgets()` or `file()`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSON file IS invalid.

Basically you have plenty of lines that are all valid JSON in itself, but they are not valid combined!

Invalid:

```
{"category":"Musician\/band","name":"Yann Tiersen (official)","id":"18359161762","created_time":"2013-03-09T23:00:54+0000"}
{"category":"Travel\/leisure","name":"Me hitchhiking around the world","id":"221159531328223","created_time":"2013-03-09T13:24:06+0000"}
```

Would be valid:

```
[
    {"category":"Musician\/band","name":"Yann Tiersen (official)","id":"18359161762","created_time":"2013-03-09T23:00:54+0000"}
,
    {"category":"Travel\/leisure","name":"Me hitchhiking around the world","id":"221159531328223","created_time":"2013-03-09T13:24:06+0000"}
]
```

You can either decode the JSON line by line, or convert it into a valid format.

Comment: I have a last question and I think I'm done. Thanks so much for help. I'll update the question in a minute

Comment: I've finally updated the question, sorry for the delay. Last one, i promise!
You might have saved an awful day for me.

Comment: `$likes` already is an array. Dont foreach it and json_encode the parts. `json_encode($likes);` works. And `file_put_contents()` exists, too.

Comment: I tried `json_encode($likes)`, and didn't work. Doesn't print anything. **edit** my bad. It works, I typed something badly. Thanks a lot for your time, you helped me a lot

Answer (score 2):

You likely have invalid JSON in `infile.json`. Per the docs of [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php):

```
NULL is returned if the json cannot be decoded or if the encoded data is deeper 
than the recursion limit.
```

Comment: I have seen the documentation, the file should not be invalid. It contains valid data from facebook. I updated the statement

Comment: I also have provided a link from where you can download the json

Comment: Your file is invalid JSON like I originally suspected. You need to convert that into an array of objects, separated by commas. They can't be separated by newlines and not wrapped with array brackets. I recommend validating your JSON in http://jsonlint.com/ in the future to simplify these troubleshooting efforts.